# entrypoint module not found after install

Tags: python-3.x, installation, setup.py

In my python project, I have this hierarchy

```
+ slack_app
  + src
      + apps
         + intro
             + \__main__.py
             + slack_app.py
  + setup.py
```

This is my setup.py:

```
setup(
  name= "my-slack-app",
  packages = find_packages(),
  entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'slack-app = src.apps.intro.__main__:main',
        ],
})
```

__main__.py:

```
def main():
    print("WORKED")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I run python3 setup.py install, then run my app which is installed in /usr/local/python3.6/bin but I always get this error when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/python3.6/bin/slack-app", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('my-slack-app==0.1.dev2+g4fd21b0.d20200309', 
   'console_scripts', 'slack-app')()
     File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
   File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in 
   load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
   File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
   File "/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], 
   level=0)
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.apps'
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `setuptools.find_packages`, then you need to have `__init__.py` files. Also you are using the so-called *src-layout* so you need to adjust the `package_dir` and set the `where` parameter of `find_packages`.

Reference:

- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages